# Is there a way to set default contents of a file in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want the following code to appear every time I create a new blank C++ file:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

int main(){
    /* code here */

    return 0;
}
```

I know I can create a new user snippet but is there a way to automatically insert it on a new black C++ file without having to type anything?

(This can be also analogously extended to Java, C, and other languages)

Comment: I suggest to change your template file and [avoid `<bits/stdc++.h>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h).

Comment: [google's search](https://www.google.com/search?q=vs+code+template+new+file) give several extensions.

Comment: I have searched in the propper VScode [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings) for settings but I do not think you can do it with VScode but an extension

Comment: @M.K thanks, I was also initially searching the docs. I will check out the extensions once.

Comment: @Jarod42 thanks, I will check out the problem with bits/stdc++.h